# Launch failed no binaries

Tags: c++, eclipse

I installed Eclipse to work with C++, but it says launch failed no binaries when I try to run it. I tried setting PE Windows Parser as I saw on Google, but in the list of binaries there is nothing, it is blank. There is no parser in the settings tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Visual Studio in the end.